# Gremlin Client Responses in the Wrong Format

Tags: node.js, gremlin

I'm trying to rewrite some code after `gremlin.createClient` was depreciated but it needs to return the data in the way it's been previously expected.

```js
const gremlin = require('gremlin');

client = new gremlin.driver.Client(`wss://${endpoint}:8182/gremlin`, {
  mimeType: 'application/json', // this seems to change how the data is returned
});

const result = await client.submit(query, {});
```

I get a result like

```json
{
  "_items": [
    1795207
  ],
  "attributes": {},
  "length": 1
}
```

Whereas I need something like

```json
[
  {
    "@type": "g:Int64",
    "@value": 1795207
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: do not indicate explicitly or use mimeType `application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json`

A bit more details:
there are several serializers on Gremlin Server, depends on server version and server setup. Probably in your case some untyped serializer registered before typed one and therefore handle request